# Python Post request returning unexpected html

Tags: python

I have this code

```
import urllib,urllib2
site="http://m.facebook.com/login.php"
data={
'email':'myemail',
'pass':''
}
data=urllib.urlencode(data)
request=urllib2.Request(site,data)
request.add_header('User-Agent','Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT')
html=urllib2.urlopen(request)
print html.read()
```

So since it's an empty password it's supposed to return a login page with an error..But instead it returns the html of the page without any error in it just as the original one.Does anybody have an idea about this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got the login page as intended based on your code..

Comment: Why not post the HTML that returned here? That'll be helpful.

Comment: @karthikr With the error?That's strange
Kjuly http://pastebin.com/dK7RuPex

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe your request was not accepted by the server.

First, you need to checkout how the front end send request, the developer tool in chrome can help you.

Besides, many websites have some mechanisms to refuse the requests from spiders, add header is not enough.I recommend you to simulate the real browser to do this.You can try selenium.

Comment: Well thanks for the advice but I can't use something third party because the thing I'm coding is really small scale

Comment: Well, if you don't want to use something third party,it would be pretty tough for you to figure out how facebook filter the requests.They can't approve someone just write a script and use it to login facebook.

Comment: Yeah I figured that much out and just moved to mechanize. :D